# Функции в js. Я запутался. Надо и ajax, и window.onload, и вернуть значение

Tags: javascript, функции

Я по-прежнему плаваю в js. Нужны Ваши пояснения, чтобы разобраться с функциями в js раз и навсегда. Речь не о стрелочных, а об обычных. Вот пример кода (т.к здесь ajax он у вас не сработает при запуске):

```js
const leftBar = document.querySelector('.left-bar');

window.onload = show_files

function show_files(){
 let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', 'php/files_list.php');
 xhr.send();
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState != 4){
   return; 
  }
  if(xhr.status == 200){
   leftBar.removeAttribute('style');
   let resp = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
   leftBar.innerHTML += (resp.length == 0) 
   ? `<p><b>Файлов загружено: ${resp.length} </b></p>` 
   : `<p><b>Файлов загружено: ${resp.length} </b></p>
   <ul id="files"></ul><br>
   <button class="padding-5" id="clear">Удалить файлы</button>`
   //Заполняем ul
   let ul = document.querySelector('#files')
   for(let i in resp){
    let li = document.createElement('li')
    li.innerHTML = resp[i];
    ul.appendChild(li)
   }
   arr = [...ul.children];
   return arr;
  }
  else if(xhr.status != 200){
   leftBar.style.border = '1px solid red'
   leftBar.innerHTML = 'Ошибка: ' + xhr.status
  }
 }
}
```

Немного прокомментирую код. Если на сервере нет файлов, то в .leftBar будет написано "Файлов загружено: 0". Если есть: "Файлов загружено: 15", список файлов и кнопка "Удалить файлы".

Но при этом мне нужно вернуть массив `arr = [...ul.children];`

Когда я ввожу arr в консоли, то она выводит массив, как надо. Но если где-то в коде нужно поработать с этой же переменной, то выходит ошибка "arr is not defined".

Итак, вопросы:
1) Как выполнить ajax и вернуть arr одновременно (только 
 асинхронно?)?
2) Почему в консоли переменная видна, а при вызове в коде - нет? В коде я прописывал, кажется, по-всякому...
3) Как js понимает, где нужно выполнить функцию, а где сделать return?
4) Почему функции иногда пишут без скобок (речь опять не о стрелочных)? Например, show_files(); и show_files;

То же самое со стрелочной функцией. Массив не возвращается...

```js
const show_files = () => {
 let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', 'php/files_list.php');
 xhr.send();
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState != 4){
   return; 
  }
  if(xhr.status == 200){
   leftBar.removeAttribute('style');
   resp = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
   leftBar.innerHTML += (resp.length == 0) 
   ? `<p><b>Файлов загружено: ${resp.length} </b></p>` 
   : `<p><b>Файлов загружено: ${resp.length} </b></p>
   <ul id="files"></ul><br>
   <button class="padding-5" id="clear">Удалить файлы</button>`
   //Заполняем ul
   let ul = document.querySelector('#files')
   for(let i in resp){
    let li = document.createElement('li')
    li.innerHTML = resp[i];
    ul.appendChild(li)
   }
   let arr = [...ul.children];
   return arr;
  }
  else if(xhr.status != 200){
   leftBar.style.border = '1px solid red'
   leftBar.innerHTML = 'Ошибка: ' + xhr.status
  }
 }
}

let arr = show_files();
```

Спасибо за Ваши ответы!

Comment: "Когда я ввожу arr в консоли, то она выводит массив, как надо." - не может быть, при показанном коде.

Comment: У меня выводит...

Answer (score 0):

а зачем вам вообще arr
вы добьавляеть в ul кторые уже есть разметке

просто там где вам нужен будет arr сделайте так

```
let arr = [...document.querySelector('#files').children]
```

Используте промисы эьл уже давно стандарт и будет ок работать везде

```
const leftBar = document.querySelector('.left-bar');

window.onload = show_files

async function show_files(){
    let data =  await fetch('php/files_list.php');
    // в дате будет что сто от сервера и потом пишите логику и верните массив
}
```

из запросов проблемно возвращать данные

Comment: Видите ли в чем дело. Мне придется сравнивать два массива. Я хотел потом сделать setInterval. Каждую 2 сек видеть актуальные файлы. И чтобы div постоянно не обновлялся, хотел сравнивать, изменились ли файлы спустя 2 секунды. Если да, обновить div, если нет - оставить без изменения. Если он регулярно будет обновляться, то текст невозможно выделить мышью...

Comment: Хотя, наверное, вы правы: сделать только ajax. Ну, а все-таки, можно ли и ajax, и вернуть значение? Чисто в учебных целях интересуюсь

Comment: show_files разве разве  что то возвращает ?

Comment: xhr.onreadystatechange возращает arr а не show_files